# How to extract keyword from text in python?

Tags: python

I wanna extract some keywords from text and print but how?

This is sample text i wanna extract from

```
text = "Merhaba bugun bir miktar bas agrisi var, genellikle sonbahar gunlerinde baslayan bu bas agrisi insanin canini sikmakta. Bu durumdan kurtulmak icin neler yapmali."
```

This is sample keywords extract from text

```
keywords = ('bas agrisi', 'kurtulmak')
```

and i wanna detect these keywords and print like;

```
bas agrisi
kurtulmak
```

how can i do this in python?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP is asking to solve an extremely basic problem without showing what he have tried so far.

Comment: I don't think you want to extract, because you have the keywords in hand, I think you should look for whether the keywords in your text exist. like: `for _ in text.split():
    for __ in keywords:
        if _ in __:
            print(f'{_} keyword found.')`

Comment: You should also show your effort, and not only ask others to do your work, please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: my friend, maybe more than 3 hours i search for this problem. Firstly i think use nlp, and then flashtext and then other libraries, but later i thougt may be i can use very simple solution. So i need this simple code. I am so new in python and i need ask question... Thanks for support.

Comment: try this: `[print(f'keywords found: {_}') for _ in text.split() if _ in keywords]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
string = "Merhaba bugun bir miktar bas agrisi var, genellikle sonbahar gunlerinde baslayan bu bas agrisi insanin canini sikmakta. Bu durumdan kurtulmak icin neler yapmali."

keywords = ('bas agrisi', 'kurtulmak')

print(*[key for key in keywords if key in string], sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
bas agrisi
kurtulmak
```

Comment: sorry bro, this answer is amazing, it solves my problem. I will accept the solution but always says in 7 minutes, in 6 minutes... downvote is by mistaken... sorry, i made it upvote

Comment: @seymenler welcome dude. I wait when you can `accept` this. I hope this helps you

Comment: @PCM thanks i don't know that ;)))

Answer (score 2):

Use `re` library to find all possible keywords.

```py
import re

text = "Merhaba bugun bir miktar bas agrisi var, genellikle sonbahar gunlerinde baslayan bu bas agrisi insanin canini sikmakta. Bu durumdan kurtulmak icin neler yapmali."
keywords = ('bas agrisi', 'kurtulmak')

result = re.findall('|'.join(keywords), text)
for key in result:
    print(key)
```

```py
bas agrisi
bas agrisi
kurtulmak
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want python to understand keywords or would you like to see words as tokens in a particular text? Because for the first one, you may need to build a machine learning mechanism or neural network to understand and extract keywords from the text. But for the second, you can use a very easy steps to tokenize words.

For example,

```
 import nltk    #need to download necessary dictionaries 
 nltk.download('punkt')
 nltk.download('stopwords')
 nltk.download('wordnet')
 text = "I wonder if I have been changed in the night. Let me think. Was 
 I the same when I got up this morning? I almost can remember feeling a 
 little different. But if I am not the same, the next question is 'Who 
 in the world am I?' Ah, that is the great puzzle!"  # This is an 
 #example of a text
 tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
 tokens  #punctuations did not removed and conceived as part of the word
 #Output will look like the following;
 ['I',
  'wonder',
  'if',
  'I',
  'have',
  'been',
  'changed',
  'in',
  'the',
  'night',
  '.',
 'Let',
  'me',
  'think',
  '.',
  'Was',
  'I',
  'the',
  'same',
  'when',
  'I',....]
  #As first, you can clean the text by lowering the letters
  tokens2 = [ word.lower() for word in tokens if word.isalpha()]
  #Second, you can remove stops words in the text. There are different 
  #libraries available for various languages but admittedly English is 
  #the best library
  from nltk.corpus import stopwords
  stop_words = stopwords.words("english")
  #You can filter the text from stop words by filtering the previously 
  #created tokens2
  tokens3 = [word for word in tokens2 if word not in stop_words] #word 
  #for word named as list comprehension
  #Tokenization is a pre-set up for the lemmatization which is a way to  
  eliminate repeating words and comprehend the stems of the words
  # lemmatization
  from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 
  lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
  lemmatizer.lemmatize('stripes', pos= 'v') # n is for noun v is for 
  #verb
  print(lemmatizer.lemmatize("stripes", 'n'))
  #output is stripe because the stem of the word stripes is stripe
  # The following is an example for using stemming
  from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer 
  stemmer = PorterStemmer()
  [stemmer.stem(word) for word in tokens3]
  #output will be 
  ['wonder',
   'chang',
   'night',
   'let',
   'think',
   'got',
   'morn',
   'almost',
   'rememb',
   'feel',
   'littl',
   'differ',
   'next',
   'question',
   'world',
   'ah',
   'great',
   'puzzl'] # From the text, stop words were eliminated. Such as I, 
    #have, been and etc. Also stems of the words retrieved.
    #One last thing to see how lemmatizer works         
    tokens4 = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, pos='n') for word in tokens3]
    tokens4 = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, pos='v') for word in tokens4]
    print(tokens4)
    #Output will be
    ['wonder', 'change', 'night', 'let', 'think', 'get', 'morning', 
    'almost', 'remember', 'feel', 'little', 'different', 'next', 
    'question', 'world', 'ah', 'great', 'puzzle']
```

I hope, I was able to explain clearly. Also, if you like to move on a little and create a neural network or such mechanism, you may use One hot coding.

Comment: Thank you mochi. This answer will open my way. I will inspect all the codes and will thank very very much. Thanks my friend.

Comment: You are welcome.